# How to call function after call api in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I want to call the second function after the first function is executed.
In other words, I want the second function to be executed only when the output of the first function is a certain value
Is there an optimal way?

```
func1() {
this.apiService.getData().subscribe(val=>{
  if(val.status ==1) {
     this.func2();
  }
})
}

func2() {
this.apiService.getData2().subscribe(val=>{
  //code
})
}
```

Comment: I dont think there is any better way, this approach seems to be fine

Comment: What do you mean with _"better"_? Asking for opinions is off-topic.

Comment: @jabaa I want to know if there is a more optimal way

Comment: Optimal is a superlative. Something is either optimal or not. It can't be **more** optimal. What do you mean with _"optimal"_? Optimal regarding, performance, regarding readability, regarding code length, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to chain observables in Angular is to use the **switchMap** operator, which maps one observable to another and unsubscribes from the previous one when a new value arrives. This way, you can avoid nested subscriptions and memory leaks. For example, you could write something like this:

```js
func1() {
  this.apiService.getData().pipe(
    // switch to the second observable if the status is 1
    switchMap(val => val.status == 1 ? this.func2() : of(null))
  ).subscribe(result => {
    // handle the result of the second observable or null
  })
}

func2() {
  // return the second observable without subscribing
  return this.apiService.getData2();
}
```

Check this for more info: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap